# Creating a query in Laravel by using `with` and `where`

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, subquery

I'm wondering it would be possible to add a `where` condition to a `with`.

Such as:

```
Comment::with('Users')->where('allowed', 'Y')->get();
```

I was trying to find a more simple way to make queries avoiding the `whereHas` method which looks quite verbose:

```
$users = Comment::whereHas('users', function($q)
{
    $q->where('allowed', 'Y');

})->get();
```

The raw query I want internally to generate should be like so:

```
select * from comments, users
where users.id = comments.user_id and
users.allowed = 'Y'
```

I'm used to work with CakePHP in which this queries look very simple:

```
$this->Comments->find('all', array('Users.allowed' => 'Y'));
```

The relationships I have defined are:

```
//Comments.php
public function Users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Users');
}

//Users.php
public function Comments(){
    return $this->hasMany('Comments');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

```
$users = User::with(array('comments' => function($q)
{
    $q->where('attachment', 1);

}))->get();
```

**Update :** Alternatively you may use a where clause in your relationship in your `User` model

```
// Relation for comments with attachment value 1
// and if hasMany relation is used
public function commentsWithAttachment()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Comment')->where('attachment', 1);
}

// Relation for all comments
// and if hasMany relation is used
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Comment');
}
```

So, you can just use

```
// Comments with attachment value 1
User::with('commentsWithAttachment')->get();

// All comments
User::with('comments')->get();
```

**Update :** I think you want all comments with users where attachment is 1, if this what you want then it should be Comment not User

```
Comment::with('user')->where('attachment', 1)->get();
```

In this case your relation should be

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User'); // if model name is User
}
```

Because one comment belongs to only one user.

Comment: That's exactly what I said I would like to avoid. Quite verbose.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't get it, can you explain ?

Comment: I posted it with `whereHas` insteas of `with`, but it still looking very large for such a simple and common operation.

Comment: Now it wouldn't work the other way around, if the relationship was defined as `belongsTo` and i want to query a connected table which has the `hasMany` relationship.
    `Comments::with('Users')->where('name', 'Paul');`

Comment: How is your relation declared ?

Comment: I am displaying the comments in a table. I don't want to display comments which authors has a value set to `N`. So right now Im doing something like `Comment::all()->get();` and I don't know where to specify the `where` clause to filter by the user parameter.

Comment: The relationship is `hasMany` for autors and `belongsTo` for comments.

Comment: You made it complicated, can you just tell me what do you want to do, what you want to retrieve from database ?

Comment: I probably used a bad example at first. Sorry. It is better illustrated in the last comment I did.

Comment: Do you want to build the raw query you gave in your example ?

Comment: Not the raw one. I know `whereRaw` but I want to know how to achieve this in the most simple way by using laravel methods.